# Sparklyr with SparkR: Trouble resolving function arguments

Tags: r, sparkr, sparklyr

I am running **Sparklyr with SparkR**.  When I try to call the `schema()` function with a data table created by `spark_read_csv()` I receive the following error (and a similar error on the `select()` and `lapply()` functions):

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘schema’ for signature
>   ‘"tbl_spark"’

Below is my version info:

> R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
>
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

...
other attached packages:
[1]

> sparklyr_1.0.9005 SparkR_2.4.1

Here is some sample code:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
library(sparklyr)

...

sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://<server>",spark_home = 
"C:/Users/paul/Downloads/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7", app_name = "sparklyr",config=config)

...

AWIDData = spark_read_csv(sc, name = "AWIDData", path = "hdfs://<server>/AWID/dataset-headers-tst.csv")

...

SparkR::schema(AWIDData)
```

I would expect this to create the schema struct for the tbl_spark data table but it has some sort of error resolving the correct function to call.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion might be a consequence of mixing functions from the two packages `SparkR` and `sparklyr`. Since you have created the connection to the data source by a `sparklyr` function (`spark_read_csv`), you would need to use the `sparklyr` function `sdf_schema` instead of `schema`.